# Individual atom font size in molecule structure using ChemFig package

Tags: chemfig, animate

I'm trying to display the bondings movement/vibration due to heat. I am able to recreate all the movement (together with animate package) except the "wagging" and "twisting" (please refer here for [explanation](http://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Spectroscopy/Vibrational_Spectroscopy/Vibrational_Modes)). The thing is that ChemFig seems to not accept the default text manipulation commands:
`\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\small`, `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge`, `\Huge`. This is the code:

```
%
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[loop,palindrome,autoplay]{animate}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}


Twisting:
\begin{animateinline}[begin={\begin{minipage}[c][6em]{12em}}, end={\end{minipage}}]{3}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:-30]{\Huge H})(-[:30]{\tiny H})}
{\Huge H}{\tiny H}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:-30]{\Large H})(-[:30]{\footnotesize H})}
{\Large H}{\footnotesize H}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:-30]{\normalsize H})(-[:30]{\normalsize H})}
{\normalsize H}{\normalsize H}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:-30]{\footnotesize H})(-[:30]{\Large H})}
{\footnotesize H}{\Large H}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:-30]{\tiny H})(-[:30]{\Huge H})}
{\tiny H}{\Huge H}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hydrogen atoms seem to change size fine (using Acrobat reader)

Comment: Are you meaning the extra HH on the right of the molecule? That is just to show that the ChemFig isn't applying the sizing inside the \chemfig command.

Comment: I see. I missed that point.

Comment: I think (?) the `chemfig` arguments are processed in math mode.  Thus, you might need `\mbox{\tiny H}` instead of `\tiny H`.

Comment: Absolutely correct, worked just great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the `chemfig` arguments are processed in math mode.  Thus, if one wishes to use size changes like `\tiny`, they need to be in an `\mbox`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[loop,palindrome,autoplay]{animate}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}


Twisting:
\begin{animateinline}[begin={\begin{minipage}[c][6em]{12em}}, end={\end{minipage}}]{3}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:-30]{\mbox{\Huge H}})(-[:30]{\mbox{\tiny H}})}
{\Huge H}{\tiny H}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:-30]{\mbox{\Large H}})(-[:30]{\mbox{\footnotesize H}})}
{\Large H}{\footnotesize H}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:-30]{H})(-[:30]{H})}
{\normalsize H}{\normalsize H}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:-30]{\mbox{\footnotesize H}})(-[:30]{\mbox{\Large H}})}
{\footnotesize H}{\Large H}
}
\newframe
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\chemfig{C(<[:165])(<:[:195])(-[:-30]{\mbox{\tiny H}})(-[:30]{\mbox{\Huge H}})}
{\tiny H}{\Huge H}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

**POSTSCRIPT**

See clemens' comments below, who indeed confirms that the arguments are processed in math mode.  Further, he notes that "atoms are placed in `\printatom` which is defined as `\newcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}`".  Thus a redefinition of this would allow the `\mbox` requirement of my answer to be alleviated.

Comment: Thanks! I did it without the {} around the command,  {\mbox ...} Is this bad practice?

Comment: `\mbox` takes a braced argument, if that is what you are asking.  While it may work without it, it would be through luck and not design.  I would stick with the braces.

Comment: I hear ya. I will stick to GOOD practice :)

Comment: @JimmyWestberg By the way, that is a cool animation you have there.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I could upload them all once done?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes My best compliments for your wonderful works.

Comment: It indeed does use mathmode for atoms. The manual tells it. Atoms are placed in `\printatom` which is defined as `\newcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}`

Comment: In other words: with a redefinition the same could be achieved without `\mbox`